# How we can do mvn install:install-file for in gradle for 3rd party transient dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, bouncycastle, trivy

We have Bouncycastle dependencies, coming from one dependency and another one. Sothey are something like that:

`implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.61'` <- explicitly added

`'bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138'` <- taken from another dependency

They have the different group name, so I can't just exclude 138. But I can't inrement it to `161` too, as is hosts nowhere in the repos.

Can I set up something to my `Gradle` script to

1. Take `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.61 jar`
2. Do something like

   `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`

but with `Gradle` where I'll put the desired format like bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:161

3. Only then do the rest of the build?

UPD

For strange reason even broken version of Maneesha's answer helped  me. I haven't succeed with the correct placing of the jar file before installing it, but it worked!

```
configurations {
    bouncyCastle
}

dependencies {
    // Other dependencies...
    
    bouncyCastle 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.61'
}

task installBouncyCastleJar {
    doLast {
        def bcFile = file('lib/bcprov-jdk14-1.61.jar')
        def groupId = 'bouncycastle'
        def artifactId = 'bcprov-jdk14'
        def version = '161'
        def packaging = 'jar'
        
        //project.repositories.mavenInstaller.install([
        //        file: bcFile,
        //        groupId: groupId,
        //        artifactId: artifactId,
        //        version: version,
        //        packaging: packaging
        //])
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
   build.dependsOn(installBouncyCastleJar)
}
```

I don't know how exactly, but using of

```
bouncyCastle 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.61'
```

and `bouncyCastle`  as separate configuration, made that `bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138` has disappeared from the "effective pom" or how it is called for Gradle and disappeared from the jar's`/lib` folder. So, no actual maven install was needed. Without adding the configuration, no exclusion helped to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it locally when you have the Jar file. Create a folder named lib in your project directory to store the Bouncy Castle JAR file. Place the `bcprov-jdk14-1.61.jar` file in the lib folder.

Modify your Gradle script (`build.gradle`) to include the following configuration,The `configurations` block defines a custom configuration named `bouncyCastle`

```
configurations {
    bouncyCastle
}

dependencies {
    // Other dependencies...
    
    bouncyCastle 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.61'
}

task installBouncyCastleJar {
    doLast {
        def bcFile = file('lib/bcprov-jdk14-1.61.jar')
        def groupId = 'bouncycastle'
        def artifactId = 'bcprov-jdk14'
        def version = '161'
        def packaging = 'jar'
        
        project.repositories.mavenInstaller.install([
                file: bcFile,
                groupId: groupId,
                artifactId: artifactId,
                version: version,
                packaging: packaging
        ])
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
   build.dependsOn(installBouncyCastleJar)
}
```

Comment: Great solution! But still have one issue running it: `> Could not get unknown property 'preBuild' for root project 'billing-ap' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: You can try `project.afterEvaluate` I updated it in the above code

Comment: What could be a reason for failing with the below error on CI CD server only, but not locally? `Could not get unknown property 'mavenInstaller' for repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.
* Try:`

Comment: You can add 
`repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}`

in the gradle script and try

Comment: how can I set up the putting the bcprov-jdk14-1.61.jar to the specific folder like /build/libs/ during the configuration run, in order to explicitly place /build/libs/ as bcFile parameter?